# Splitting a string and assigning values to variables

Tags: vb.net, split

I am trying to split a string and take the split parts and assign them to variables.  This works fine with the first variable but I cannot get the second variable to work.

```
For Each columnQuarter As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Dim s As String = columnQuarter.ColumnName
            Dim words As String() = s.Split("-")
            Dim Year As String = words(0)
            Dim Quarter As String = words(1)
            Debug.WriteLine(Year)
            Debug.WriteLine(Quarter)
```

At line "Dim Quarter As String = words(1)" I get error code "IndexOutofRangeException was unhandled. Index was outside the bounds of the array."

An example of a ColumnName would be 2012-Q1.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Here is the code that I use to add my columns to my dataTable.  As you can see my first two columns do not contain "-".

```
tickerColumn = New DataColumn("Ticker", Type.GetType("System.String"))
consistencyColumn = New DataColumn("Consistency", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
dt.Columns.Add(tickerColumn)
dt.Columns.Add(consistencyColumn)

    With Me
        lr = Now.Year - 1901
        For i = 1 To lr
            column = New DataColumn
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
            column.ColumnName = Now.Year - i & "-Q4"
            dt.Columns.Add(column)

            column = New DataColumn
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
            column.ColumnName = Now.Year - i & "-Q3"
            dt.Columns.Add(column)

            column = New DataColumn
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
            column.ColumnName = Now.Year - i & "-Q2"
            dt.Columns.Add(column)

            column = New DataColumn
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
            column.ColumnName = Now.Year - i & "-Q1"
            dt.Columns.Add(column)
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: What is the length of words after you call Split("-")? And what is the value you get for words(0)?

Comment: The length of the words after I call Split("-") would be 2 letters (Q1).  The value I get for words(0) is 2012.

Comment: Have you verified that **all** columns in your DataTable have a hyphen in them?  That exception means that there was not a second element in the split array.

Comment: I mean what is the length of the string array that you have named words. I.e. what does Debug.WriteLine(words.Length) give?

Comment: Your code works fine. Make sure the value is indeed in the format "2012-Q1". If the format looks OK, then maybe the dash in the string is not a standard dash...

Comment: also what is the value of your columnQuarter.ColumnName when your exception is thrown? Try adding Debug.WriteLine(columnQuarter.ColumnName) just before you declare words

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I edited my original post to address your question about all columns in my DataTable having a hyphen in them.  Any additional ideas?

Comment: So your first two columns with cause an IndexOutofRangeException. Are you excluding them? If you are what is columnQuarter.ColumnName when your exception is thrown?

Comment: @openshac Debug.WriteLine(words.Length) gives a 1. Debug.WriteLine(columnQuarter.ColumnName) gives Ticker.  Please see the additional information that I added to my original post.

Comment: You have 2 columns, called Ticker and Consistency.  These do not have any hyphens, and would cause your exception.  See LarsTech answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your first two columns do NOT have the dash, try filtering them out:

```
For Each columnQuarter As DataColumn In dt.Columns
  Dim s As String = columnQuarter.ColumnName
    If s.Contains("-") Then
      Dim words As String() = s.Split("-")
      Dim Year As String = words(0)
      Dim Quarter As String = words(1)
      Debug.WriteLine(Year)
      Debug.WriteLine(Quarter)
    End If
Next
```