# Splitting a string and assigning values to variables in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to answer a similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649128/splitting-a-string-and-assigning-values-to-variables) in R.

I'm working with a dataset including a variable that concatenates 30 values of a string with numeric values in parentheses.  The separate combinations of strings and parenthetical numbers are comma-separated.

**IMPORTANT: Sometimes, string values may be repeating.**

For example, in `df` the `var` might be:

```
id    var
1     Videos (10.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.3), Videos (1)
2     Videos (11.1), Dogs (10.5), Cats (8.4), Dogs (1)
3     Cars (12.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.5), Games (2)
4     Cars (14.1), Music (9.5), Dogs (8.6)
5     Horses (10.1), Antelope (9.5), Music (8.7)
6     Music (10.1), Videos (9.0), Games (8.9)
```

What I would like to produce is additional columns where each unique string value in `var` has its own column, and the value for that column is the number in parentheses (when available). **Something that is a bit tricky (to me) is that when a string value (e.g. `Videos`) is repeated, I would like to sum the numeric values.**

So, in the dataset I've produced, the ideal *output* would be:

```
id   Videos   Music   Games    Dogs   Cats    Cars   Horses   Antelope
1    11.1     9.5     8.3      NA     NA      NA     NA       NA
2    11.1     NA      NA       11.5   8.4     NA     NA       NA
3    NA       9.5     10.5      NA     NA      12.1   NA       NA
4    NA       9.5     NA       8.6     NA     14.1   NA       NA
5    NA       8.7     NA       8.6     NA     NA   10.1       9.5
5    9.0       10.1   8.7      NA     NA      NA     NA       NA
```

Any thoughts on how one would go about doing this in R?

**EDIT: Real data included below:**

```
 my_df<-data.frame(id=1:20, var= c("PeopleBlogs(2.88)", "Music(3.90)", "Entertainment(3.05),Music(5.10),Music(2.28)", 
"Sports(1.02)", "NonprofitsActivism(0.20),FilmAnimation(0.58)", 
"Music(3.60),Music(1.42),Music(7.60)", "GadgetsGames(0.52)", 
"Music(9.17),PeopleBlogs(0.33),PeopleBlogs(1.58),Music(8.82),Entertainment(1.38),PeopleBlogs(0.45),PeopleBlogs(0.58),Entertainment(0.92),FilmAnimation(1.60),FilmAnimation(7.57),Music(2.28),Entertainment(3.18),Entertainment(4.98),Music(0.48),FilmAnimation(0.28),FilmAnimation(0.18),Entertainment(5.97),Entertainment(1.35)", 
"FilmAnimation(2.42),GadgetsGames(3.92)", "PeopleBlogs(4.38),GadgetsGames(15.47)", 
"Entertainment(3.52)", "PeopleBlogs(0.22),Music(1.15),PetsAnimals(3.50),PeopleBlogs(2.78),PeopleBlogs(3.27)", 
"Music(2.05),PeopleBlogs(0.20)", "Music(3.48),Music(4.65),Music(0.55)", 
"Entertainment(0.78)", "Entertainment(4.35),PeopleBlogs(2.33),Comedy(7.05),PeopleBlogs(7.27)", 
"Entertainment(0.50)", "Education(1.73)", "Education(0.67)", 
"GadgetsGames(17.35),Education(7.40),NewsPolitics(0.35)"))
```

Comment: So when they are repeated in a row, do you want to sum them?

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes! I will clarify my language to make this more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach for you. First, you use `cSplit()` from the `splitstackshape` package. You are splitting the `var` column by `,` for the first time and reshaping the data format. Then, you split the `var` column again separating by a space. By this time, you have a data.table, not a data.frame. Using the `data.table` package, you do two things. One is you remove `(` and `)` and convert character to numeric. Then, as you requested, you sum the numbers by `id` and `var_1`. Finally, you use `dcast()` in the `data.table` package and have the desired output. I hope this will help you.

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
                   var = c("Videos (10.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.3), Videos (1)",
                         "Videos (11.1), Dogs (10.5), Cats (8.4), Dogs (1)",
                         "Cars (12.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.5), Games (2)",
                         "Cars (14.1), Music (9.5), Dogs (8.6)",
                         "Horses (10.1), Antelope (9.5), Music (8.7)",
                         "Music (10.1), Videos (9.0), Games (8.9)"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

cSplit(mydf, "var", sep = ",", direction = "long") %>%
cSplit("var", sep = " ", direction = "wide") -> foo

foo[, var_2 := as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "\\(|\\)", replacement = "", x = var_2))][,
list(total = sum(var_2)), by = list(id, var_1)] %>%
dcast(id ~ var_1, value.var = "total")


#  id Antelope Cars Cats Dogs Games Horses Music Videos
#1:  1       NA   NA   NA   NA   8.3     NA   9.5   11.1
#2:  2       NA   NA  8.4 11.5    NA     NA    NA   11.1
#3:  3       NA 12.1   NA   NA  10.5     NA   9.5     NA
#4:  4       NA 14.1   NA  8.6    NA     NA   9.5     NA
#5:  5      9.5   NA   NA   NA    NA   10.1   8.7     NA
#6:  6       NA   NA   NA   NA   8.9     NA  10.1    9.0
```

EDIT

With your real data, Ananda's and my codes do not work. This is because you do not have a space between characters and numbers (e.g., `Videos(10.1)`), whereas your original sample data do have a space between them (e.g., `Videos (10.1)`). Modifying my original answer, the following will do the job for you. I uploaded a part of the result.

```
cSplit(my_df, "var", sep = ",", direction = "long") %>%
cSplit("var", sep = "(", direction = "wide") -> foo


foo[, var_2 := as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "\\)", replacement = "", x = var_2))][,
list(total = sum(var_2)), by = list(id, var_1)] %>%
dcast(id ~ var_1, value.var = "total")

#    id Comedy Education Entertainment FilmAnimation GadgetsGames Music NewsPolitics
#1:  1     NA        NA            NA            NA           NA    NA           NA
#2:  2     NA        NA            NA            NA           NA  3.90           NA
#3:  3     NA        NA          3.05            NA           NA  7.38           NA
#4:  4     NA        NA            NA            NA           NA    NA           NA
#5:  5     NA        NA            NA          0.58           NA    NA           NA
```

Comment: I had done almost the same: `cSplit(mydf, "var", ",", "long") %>% .[, var := gsub(" (", "|", gsub(")", "", var, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)] %>% cSplit(., "var", "|") %>% dcast(id ~ var_1, value.var = "var_2", fun.aggregate = sum, fill = NA)` (using magrittr). +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thank you for sharing your code. Using `fun.aggregate = sum`, we can make the code shorter. Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: @jazzurro This code is returning the error: `Error in gsub(pattern = "\\(|\\)", replacement = "", x = var_2) : object 'var_2' not found`

Comment: @roody I ran the code above again. On my side, I do not see the error message. Could you check if you have all latest packages above and use `mydf` and run the code? Could you also check if your data set is identical to your sample?

Comment: @jazzurro Hi there! I updated with actual data from my dataset...I am getting the same error message regarding var_2. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @roody I added another version for your real data. Please have a look.

Comment: @jazzurro Thank you! This worked...but, I had to make a minor modification w/ my full dataset. I had to skip the `gsub(pattern` part of your code to manually remove the parentheses using `stringr`'s `str_replace_all`. (i.e. `str_replace_all(foo$var_2, fixed("("), "")` I'm not sure what was wrong with my dataset, but this minor modification did the trick.

Comment: @roody Glad to hear that you found your way based on my suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)    

mydf %>%
  mutate(both = var %>% stri_split_fixed(", ") ) %>%
  unnest(both) %>%
  separate(both, c("category", "value.string"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(value = value.string %>% extract_numeric) %>%
  group_by(id, category) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(category, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Another method without additional libraries
# vector with data to split
X <- c("Videos (10.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.3), Videos (1)",
       "Videos (11.1), Dogs (10.5), Cats (8.4), Dogs (1)",
       "Cars (12.1), Music (9.5), Games (8.5), Games (2)",
       "Cars (14.1), Music (9.5), Dogs (8.6)",
       "Horses (10.1), Antelope (9.5), Music (8.7)")

# custom split function
g <- function(x, ...) {
  x <- chartr(")", " ", x)
  x <- chartr(",", "\n", x)
  x <- read.table(text=x, sep="(", strip.white=TRUE)
  L <- levels(x$V1)
  V <- numeric(0)
  for (l in L) {
    V <- c(V, sum(x$V2[x$V1==l]))
  }
  names(V) <- L
  return(V)
}

# making a data.frame element by element
Y <- data.frame(case=1:length(X))
for (i in 1:length(X)) {
  rw <- g(X[i]) 
  for (n in names(rw)) {
    Y[i,n] <- rw[n]
  }
}

Y

  case Games Music Videos Cats Dogs Cars Antelope Horses
1    1   8.3   9.5   11.1   NA   NA   NA       NA     NA
2    2    NA    NA   11.1  8.4 11.5   NA       NA     NA
3    3  10.5   9.5     NA   NA   NA 12.1       NA     NA
4    4    NA   9.5     NA   NA  8.6 14.1       NA     NA
5    5    NA   8.7     NA   NA   NA   NA      9.5   10.1
```